# Different GUID formats for Xrm.Page.getAttribute(...).getValue[0].id

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, guid

I want to read two GUIDs in my web-resource to compare them. Both lookup fields have the same related type and an `onChange` listener attached.

If I populate the header lookupfield first and the body lookup field second, I get the following result ids:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("headerLookupField").getValue()[0].id: "91381930-5ae3-e911-812a0050568d4344"
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("bodyLookupField").getValue()[0].id: "{91381930-5AE3-E911-812A-0050568D4344}"
```

If I do it vice versa, I get both times the correct formatted body id. Now my question:

**Why do I get a different GUID format if I populate the header lookup field first?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's inconsistent across the system - probably a bug or by design :)

Whenever I'm accessing GUID, this becomes my practice.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace("{", "").replace("}", "")

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lookupfield").getValue()[0].id.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
```

On a side note, `Xrm.Page` is deprecated in latest version - so time to use the below syntax. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/executioncontext/getformcontext)

```
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();    
var attr = formContext.getAttribute("lookupfield").getValue()[0].id.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
```

Comment: Rather than doing multiple `replaces`, you can do a single regex: `id.replace(/[{}]/g, '')`